# Check if a post has term inside loop

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, loop, terms

I'm trying to do a query for a post with three terms in a custom taxonomy. Then, in the loop, I want to output just the posts with one of these terms:

```
$args = array(
  'post_status'    => array( 'publish' ),
  'tax_query'      => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'prr',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => ['proteger', 'respetar', 'remediar'],
    ),
  )
);
$prr_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
if ( $prr_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $prr_query->have_posts() ) {
        $prr_query->the_post();
        if (has_term('proteger')) {
          the_title();
        }
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

It does not work.

If I do a loop without conditional, it works:

```
if ( $prr_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $prr_query->have_posts() ) {
        $prr_query->the_post();
          the_title();
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

If I do a `var_dump($prr_query)` I get this:

https://pastebin.com/jZq5t8Bt

I can see, in this query, that post objects do not includes term list.

How can I output just the posts that has a specific term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with custom taxonomies, you must mention that custom taxonomy in `has_term()`.

```
if ( $prr_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $prr_query->have_posts() ) {
        $prr_query->the_post();
        if (has_term('proteger', 'prr')) {
          the_title();
        }
    }
}
```

[Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)